# Java cucumber - Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

[Issue Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We98B.jpg) Trying to implement cucumber to do some automated tests. When I try to execute my feature file(myfeature.feature), I am getting below error

***Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main***

**Project path**

```
src
 -cucumber(package)
    -CucumberRunner.java
  -cucumber.feature(package)
    -myfeature.feature
```

**Class code:**

```
package cucumber;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import cucumber.junit.Cucumber.Options;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @Options (
            format = {"pretty", "json:target/"},
            features = {"src/cucumber/"}
            )
    public class CucumberRunner {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same problem you should add cucumber java dependency in pom.xml below is dependency and build the project

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```